# Regex - lookahead assertion

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have problem with lookahead assertion (?=). For example, I have expression:

```
/Win(?=2000)/
```

It match `Win`, if expression is like `Win2000`, `Win2000fgF`. I have next expression:

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z]).*$
```

It match for digit and lower case letter, for example: `45dF`, `4Dd`. But I don't know, why it works and match all characters :) I haven't characters, which are before `(?=.*\d)`. I think, only this expression should work:

```
^.\*(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z]).*$
```

(with `\*` before expression).

Could you explain it?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Let's say we are the regex engine and apply the regex `^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z]).*$` to the string `2a`.

Starting at position 0 (before the first character):

1. `^`: Make sure we're at the start of the string: OK
2. `(?=`: Let's check if the following regex could match...
3. `.*`: match any number of characters -> `2a`. OK.
4. `\d`: Nope, we're already at the end. Let's go back one character: `a` --> No, doesn't match. Go back another one: `2` --> MATCH!
5. `)`: End of lookahead, match successful. We're *still* at position 0!
6. `(?=`: Let's check if the following regex could match...
7. `.*`: match any number of characters -> `2a`. OK.
8. `[a-z]`: Nope, we're already at the end. Let's go back one character: `a` --> MATCH!
9. `)`:  End of lookahead, match successful. We're *still* at position 0!
10. `.*`: match any number of characters -> `2a` --> MATCH!
11. `$`: Let's see - are we at the end of the string? Yes, we are! --> MATCH!
12. Hey, we've reached the end of the regex. Great. Match completed!

Comment: Thanks for great explanation. Could you tell me, why            ^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])$ (without .* at the end) doesn't work for 2a? This regex should match?

Comment: Well, imagine you leave out step 10 - the regex engine is still at position 0, so it fails in matching the `$`.

Answer (score 4):

lookaheads don't match, they assert.

this means that if you use a lookahead, you need something that *will* match what you want if you want to go any further.