# Regex negation?

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I'm playing Regex Golf (http://regex.alf.nu/) and I'm doing the Abba hole.  I have the following regex that matches the wrong side entirely (which is what I was trying to do):

```
(([\w])([\w])\3\2)
```

However, I'm trying to negate it now so it matches the other side.  I can't seem to figure that part out.  I tried:

```
(?!([\w])([\w])\3\2)
```

But that didn't work.  Any tips from the regex masters?

Comment: The wrong side? What side? Please provide a complete context.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can make it much shorter (and get more points) by simply using `.` and removing unnecessary parens:

```
^(?!.*(.)(.)\2\1)
```

It just makes sure that there's no "abba" ("abba" here means 4 letters in that particular order we don't want to match) in any part of the string without having to match the whole word.

Comment: I know this is old, but could you explain how `?!` works please? More specifically, why `(?!(.)(.)\2\1)` matches everything.

Comment: @AdiBradfield `(?!a)a` will never match anything because after `(?! ... )` group there is `a` and `(?!a)` prevents a match if after it, there is `a` (what's inside). Similarly, `(?!a)b` will always match a `b`, because while the `(?!a)` prevents a match if it is followed by `a`, it will never happen because there is a `b` after it. By extension,, `^(?!.*a)` will prevent a match if any line contains `a`. The anchor and the `.*` are important because otherwise, the pattern will start to match after any `a` that might exist (because after that point, there are no more `a` to prevent the match.

Comment: Okay, yeah that makes perfect sense. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: @Zikato It is working; the regex simply matches an empty line, not that it matters if you are only checking for a match or not, see http://i.stack.imgur.com/5MzvR.png

Answer (score 2):

Using the explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/406408/584663

I came up with: `^((?!((\w)(\w)\4\3)).)*$`

Answer (score 2):

The key here turns out to be the leading caret, ^, and the .*

(?! ...) is a look-ahead construct, and so does not advance the regex processing engine.

/(?! ...)/ on its own will correctly return a negative result for items matching the expression within; **but** for items which do not match (...) the regex engine continues processing. However if your regex only contains the (?! ) there is nothing left to process, and the regex processing position never advances. (See this [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3798446/920324)).

Apparently since the remaining regex is empty, it matches any zero-width segment of a string, i.e. it matches any string.

#### [begin SWAG]

With the caret ^ present, the regex engine is able to recognize that you are looking for a real answer and that you do not want it to tell you the string contains zero-width components.

#### [end SWAG]

Thus it is able to correctly fail to match when the (?! ) succeeds.

Comment: To make your SWAG more precise, the caret does not allow the engine to find zero length matches that are not at the beginning of the string.