# Regex - nested lookahead assertion

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

suppose we want to match all `one`(s) between `<out>...</out>` in this text (option: **dot matches all**):

```
<out>hello!</out>
<nx1>home one</nx1>
<nx2>living</nx2>
<out>one text
text one continues 
and at last here ends one</out>
<m2>dog one</m2>
<out>bye!</out>
```

let's say we use this pattern:

```
one(?=(?:(?!<out>).)*</out>)
```

I really appreciate it if someone explains how regex engine process that pattern step-by-step and where it would be(position in the original text) in every phase of processing;(something like accepted @[Tim Pietzcker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20670/tim-pietzcker)'s helpful explanation for this question: [Regex - lookahead assertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798282/regex-lookahead-assertion))

Comment: The provided pattern will not match all `one`(s) between `out` tags. eg. the third line which contains multiple `one`(s)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Many](http://regex101.com/) [tools](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl) exist to automatically explain what your regex does, character by character.

The idea behind it, though, is that you want to check `one` is followed by `</out>` while forbidding to enter a new `out` tag: if there's a `...</out>` following and we haven't entered a new `<out>...</out>` structure, we know we are inside one already.

So the regex will match `one` if it is followed by `</out>` and if there's no `<out>` between the two.

The work is done by `(?:(?!<out>).)*`: the `.` matches only if it is not the first `<` in `<out>`. So we can go up to `</out>` only by consuming characters that are not this `<` followed by `out>`.

---

A speed improvement would be:

```
one(?=(?:[^<]*+|<(?!out>))*+</out>)
```

Stepping inside the negative lookahead at each character greatly increases the cost of matching this character. Here `[^<]*+` will match directly up to the next suspicious `<`, and we perform the negative look ahead check only when we have to.

Comment: thanks for your response; I didn't understand the role of `.` and `*` in `(?:(?!<out>).)*`; so engine check 5 characters(length of `<out>`) from where it is right now(just after `one` (line4)) and see that it's not that(it's:" text") and now `.`: which is line break???

Comment: @wiki: Don't forget that look-ahead are [zero width](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and don't consume characters! `(?!<out>).` on `abc` will match `a`: we start behind the first character, and `(?!<out>)` checks that the first 5 characters aren't `<out>`. There aren't, so the regex goes on (we're still before the `a`) and `.` matches `a`. When repeating the pattern with `*`, the regex performs the lookahead check at each character before matching it. Is it clearer?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the explanation taken from [here](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=one%28%3F%3D%28%3F%3A%28%3F%21%3Cout%3E%29.%29%2a%3C%2Fout%3E%29):

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  one                      'one'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        <out>                    '<out>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      .                        any character except \n
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    </out>                   '</out>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Comment: thanks but RegexBuddy can do much better than that! I know that `(?!` is a negative lookahead assertion! but what I want to know is it's function in that above mentioned pattern; check the @Tim Pietzcker's explanation